# Awslogs logging driver issue - NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain

Tags: docker, amazon-cloudwatch, docker-for-mac

Docker compose addition for logging:

```
   app:
        logging:
              driver: awslogs
              options:
                awslogs-region: eu-west-3
                awslogs-group: myappLogGroup
```

I have added my AWS credentials to my mac using the aws configure command and the credentials are stored correctly in ~/.aws/credentials.

I am using docker desktop 2.2.0.4.

When I run docker-compose up I get the following error:

> ERROR: for app Cannot start service app: Failed to initialize logging driver: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated. For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

I believe this is because credentials need to be present in Docker Daemon.

Also, something I learnt is that it's not enough to provide aws credentials to the client. As per docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/#credentials):

> You must provide AWS credentials to the Docker daemon[...]

Is it possible that the actual `~./aws/credentials` file should be mounted **within** the Docker Desktop Virtual Machine?

Honestly I have been trying to fix this for 4 days and I am running out of ideas... Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem right now

Comment: Sorry Mate it has been ages since this happened to me, I do not remember even the context. Good luck!